# include with will_paginate

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

Using Rails 3.2. I have an individual Shop post, and each shop has reviews. I intend to load the reviews by ajax (which will be done later) via will_paginate.

The following line loads all reviews:

```
@spot = Shop.find(params[:id], :include => [:reviews])
```

I try to paginate the reviews using will_paginate, but haven't figured out how to paginate just the reviews.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch them separatedly.

```
@spot = Shop.find(params[:id])

@reviews = @spot.reviews.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Comment: Doesn't this introduce n+1 design problem?

Comment: no. It will just do 1 more query, unless you are fetching multiple shops but that's not what I understood from your question.